# NoClassDefFoundError when accessing web service

Tags: java, web-services, maven, tomcat, classloader

I am currently trying to incorporate a web service into my application. I do not have access to the web service itself but is accessed through a jar file. Below is the code which accesses the web service:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.String;
import com.zf.fileviewing.connection.FVConnectData;
import com.zf.fileviewing.connection.FVConnector;
import java.net.URL;

public class CheckOutAxalant implements Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public List<String> CheckoutAxalant(String docCid) 
{
    List<String> fileNames;
    String userId="";

    FVConnectData fvData = new FVConnectData();
    fvData.setWsKeyword("");
    fvData.setWsUrl("");
    FVConnector con = new FVConnector(fvData);

    // get all filenames of document
    try
    {
       fileNames = con.getAllFileNames(docCid, userId);
       for (String value : fileNames)
       {
             System.out.println("filename: " + value);
       }
       return fileNames;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
       e.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }


}
```

The error occurs on the line:

```
FVConnectData fvData = new FVConnectData();
```

The full stack trace is as follows:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/zf/fileviewing/connection/FVConnectData
at com.zf.proceed.service.checkout.CheckOutAxalant.<init>(CheckOutAxalant.java:15)
at com.zf.proceed.gui.ConversionsCreateNewConversion.<init>(ConversionsCreateNewConversion.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:129)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getSelectItems(InputRenderer.java:53)
at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:71)
at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:65)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at org.primefaces.component.wizard.WizardRenderer.encodeCurrentStep(WizardRenderer.java:174)
at org.primefaces.component.wizard.WizardRenderer.encodeContent(WizardRenderer.java:204)
at org.primefaces.component.wizard.WizardRenderer.encodeMarkup(WizardRenderer.java:159)
at org.primefaces.component.wizard.WizardRenderer.encodeEnd(WizardRenderer.java:62)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:424)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am extremely stuck on this as I am unable to access the web service.

Also FYI, If I ran the same code but adapt it into  a normal Java Application it works no problem.

Comment: are you deploying in some application server? if you are working with maven you need to install at your local repo.

Comment: I am using maven and tomcat. I have to be honest, my company is making me use maven and i dont 100% understand what it is, why i need it and how to use it. Could you please explain what you mean by `you need to install at your local repo`

Comment: I believe I have solved this issue by adding the Jar file to tomcat's classpath as well as the project classpath. I do not know why this happened as other jar files are working fine without being in TomCat's classpath.

Comment: if you use maven you have a local repo, call .m2 where you have all the jars that you need, so when you import a jar, if you don't do mvn install, the jar that you need don't be at your local repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classloader issue: `NoClassDefFoundError: com/zf/fileviewing/connection/FVConnectData`.

Are you sure all the dependencies are present in the application you deploy? Look first at the import in `FVConnectData`.

EDIT :

To the JAR file you use for the webservice call, use the [`mvn install:install-file`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) goal. It will install the artifact in your local repository and make it available to MAven. You can then add it to your pom.xml in the `dependencies` section (provide the groupdId, artifactId and version).

You can verify that it has been added to the dependencies of your project by calling `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: Sorry I do not follow. What am I looking for and where?

Comment: Inspect the imports of the `FVConnectData` class and verify that all those package are available in the dependencies (JAR) of your web service. You can also compare the dependencies with those listed in your IDE, one of those is either missing or another version of the JAR is present.

Comment: The FVConnectData is within the web service which as i mentioned I do not have access to

Comment: If I open up the jar and the class in the jar it comes up with source not found and then shows what appears to be the FVConnectData class with very strange syntax. Would it help if i uploaded this?

Comment: Also, i dont see how the imports within FVConnectData could be the problem if it runs fine independently. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Ok, I did not understand you had not access to the jar source files. If needed you could decompile the class (using jd -http://jd.benow.ca/ or something similar). But the thing is that, if you application run as a normal Java Application, it has the correct dependencies. You can compare that to the way you run the application that cause the `NoClassDefFoundError` to discover which dependency is missing or erroneous.

Comment: The only differences in how they run are, standalone it does not return a value and the docCid is stored within that method. The line to call this method from my web application is: `this.possibleFiles = checkout.CheckoutAxalant(docCid);`

Comment: My guess is that there is a difference in the classloader. You can learn more about how to resolve the `NoClassDefFoundError` in http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-how-to.html

Comment: Nothing in that that helped me im afraid.

Comment: I have come across this statement - NoClassDefFoundError comes when problematic class was present when your compiled your application but they are not in classpath while you running your program. How can I ensure that it is in the classpath when compiled and at runtime?

Comment: That was my point. There first problem you have is to find which exact dependency is missing. According to the logs it is one of the import of the `FVConnectData` class. You could also use the `-verbose:class` argument when running Java but it generate a lot of information.

Comment: I am using windows, how would I use that statement? ie where to type it in and where to run java from as i am doing it in eclipse atm

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to move the jar files to the default server lib directory in your client side. For tomcat, it would be `...\apache-tomcat-7.0.81\lib`

Please check  [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://coderanch.com/t/564131/framework/java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-basic-webservice) for more details.